# Kafka brokers down with fully written storages

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

### Kafka brokers down with fully written storages

I have tried produce as much messages as broker could handle. With fully written storages (8GB) brokers all stopped and they can't up again with this error

#### logs of brokers trying to restart

```
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,774] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,774] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,842] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,844] INFO Shutting down SupportedServerStartable (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2020-04-28 04:33:58,847] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,844] INFO Closing BaseMetricsReporter (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,844] INFO Waiting for metrics thread to exit (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,844] INFO Shutting down KafkaServer (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2020-04-28 04:34:05,845] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-28 04:33:58,847] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,847] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,847] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,854] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,942] INFO Shutting down SupportedServerStartable (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,942] INFO Closing BaseMetricsReporter (io.confluent.support.metrics.BaseMetricsReporter)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,942] INFO Waiting for metrics thread to exit (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,942] INFO Shutting down KafkaServer (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2020-04-28 04:33:59,942] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-04-28 04:37:18,938] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-22, kafka-connect-offset-15, kafka-connect-offset-16, kafka-connect-offset-2, __consumer_offsets-30, kafka-connect-offset-7, kafka-connect-offset-13, __consumer_offsets-8, __consumer_offsets-21, kafka-connect-offset-8, kafka-connect-status-2, kafka-connect-offset-5, __consumer_offsets-4, __consumer_offsets-27, __consumer_offsets-7, __consumer_offsets-9, __consumer_offsets-46, kafka-connect-offset-19, __consumer_offsets-25, __consumer_offsets-35, __consumer_offsets-41, __consumer_offsets-33, __consumer_offsets-23, __consumer_offsets-49, kafka-connect-offset-20, kafka-connect-offset-3, __consumer_offsets-47, __consumer_offsets-16, __consumer_offsets-28, kafka-connect-config-0, kafka-connect-offset-9, kafka-connect-offset-17, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-36, kafka-connect-status-1, __consumer_offsets-42, __consumer_offsets-3, __consumer_offsets-18, __consumer_offsets-37, __consumer_offsets-15, __consumer_offsets-24, kafka-connect-offset-10, kafka-connect-offset-24, kafka-connect-status-4, __consumer_offsets-38, __consumer_offsets-17, __consumer_offsets-48, kafka-connect-offset-23, kafka-connect-offset-21, kafka-connect-offset-0, __consumer_offsets-19, __consumer_offsets-11, kafka-connect-status-0, __consumer_offsets-13, kafka-connect-offset-18, __consumer_offsets-2, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-6, __consumer_offsets-14, kafka-connect-offset-14, kafka-connect-offset-22, kafka-connect-offset-6, perf-test4-0, kafka-connect-status-3, kafka-connect-offset-11, kafka-connect-offset-12, __consumer_offsets-20, __consumer_offsets-0, kafka-connect-offset-4, __consumer_offsets-44, __consumer_offsets-39, kafka-connect-offset-1, __consumer_offsets-12, __consumer_offsets-45, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-5, __consumer_offsets-26, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-34, __consumer_offsets-10, __consumer_offsets-32, __consumer_offsets-40) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)
[2020-04-28 04:37:18,990] INFO [ReplicaManager broker=2] Broker 2 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-22,kafka-connect-offset-15,kafka-connect-offset-16,kafka-connect-offset-2,__consumer_offsets-30,kafka-connect-offset-7,kafka-connect-offset-13,__consumer_offsets-8,__consumer_offsets-21,kafka-connect-offset-8,kafka-connect-status-2,kafka-connect-offset-5,__consumer_offsets-4,__consumer_offsets-27,__consumer_offsets-7,__consumer_offsets-9,__consumer_offsets-46,kafka-connect-offset-19,__consumer_offsets-25,__consumer_offsets-35,__consumer_offsets-41,__consumer_offsets-33,__consumer_offsets-23,__consumer_offsets-49,kafka-connect-offset-20,kafka-connect-offset-3,__consumer_offsets-47,__consumer_offsets-16,__consumer_offsets-28,kafka-connect-config-0,kafka-connect-offset-9,kafka-connect-offset-17,__consumer_offsets-31,__consumer_offsets-36,kafka-connect-status-1,__consumer_offsets-42,__consumer_offsets-3,__consumer_offsets-18,__consumer_offsets-37,__consumer_offsets-15,__consumer_offsets-24,kafka-connect-offset-10,kafka-connect-offset-24,kafka-connect-status-4,__consumer_offsets-38,__consumer_offsets-17,__consumer_offsets-48,kafka-connect-offset-23,kafka-connect-offset-21,kafka-connect-offset-0,__consumer_offsets-19,__consumer_offsets-11,kafka-connect-status-0,__consumer_offsets-13,kafka-connect-offset-18,__consumer_offsets-2,__consumer_offsets-43,__consumer_offsets-6,__consumer_offsets-14,kafka-connect-offset-14,kafka-connect-offset-22,kafka-connect-offset-6,perf-test4-0,kafka-connect-status-3,kafka-connect-offset-11,kafka-connect-offset-12,__consumer_offsets-20,__consumer_offsets-0,kafka-connect-offset-4,__consumer_offsets-44,__consumer_offsets-39,kafka-connect-offset-1,__consumer_offsets-12,__consumer_offsets-45,__consumer_offsets-1,__consumer_offsets-5,__consumer_offsets-26,__consumer_offsets-29,__consumer_offsets-34,__consumer_offsets-10,__consumer_offsets-32,__consumer_offsets-40 and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory /opt/kafka/data/logs. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2020-04-28 04:37:18,990] INFO Stopping serving logs in dir /opt/kafka/data/logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2020-04-28 04:37:18,992] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [__confluent.support.metrics-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-04-28 04:37:18,996] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /opt/kafka/data/logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

#### Prometheus monitoring snapshot

[image]

**I hope to prevent this situation before broker down with solutions like remove previous messages for enough space or something. is there any best practice recommended for this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure two parameters on your kafka: `log.retention.hours` and `log.retention.bytes`. The two parameters are "how many data I would store before rotate and for how many time I would store the data before rotate? Try to improve those values if you wanna store more data or reduce your retention time.

Another thing that you can take a look if the problem is the storage is your logs. The logs generated can use a lot of space. In this point you need to put some rotate technique. Take a look on the size of your `logs` folder.

Comment: Well I put an env `KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES = "9000000000"` because I am using confluent.
And my storage hit 12Gib with the brokers down again.

Comment: Can you check the logs and the data folder. How many space each one was occupying? For this point maybe you can identify. Another thing that you can do is get smaller values on those fields, indicating that the older data will be leaved when reach the maximum value or time

Comment: Finally I got a insight, log.retention.bytes was working well.
The matter was `log.cleaner.backoff.ms` and its default value's 15000ms.
I guess I tried to consume too fast to feel about log cleaner's work.
Thanks a lot :)